# Proving that a closed set contains a set and its closure.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose that $G \subset A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A$ is closed. How would I show that $\bar{G}\subset A?$ ($\bar{G}$ means the closure of G.)

My first guess was to use the proposition the that the closure of a set is closed (which I proved). So, $G\subset A \implies \bar{G}\subset \bar{A} \implies \bar{G}\subset A.$ But this proof seems incomplete.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is not incomplete but completely correct.

Comment: Maybe it could be regarded as incomplete in the sense the fact the closure is closed doesn't (at least not immediately) give either of the implications. The second implication is because if $A$ is closed then $A = \overline{A}$, and the first implication is by definition of closure and the proposition and I suppose that $\overline{A} \supset A$. I think it depends on how much detail is needed. The second implication in particular requires $A$ be closed, otherwise take $A$ to  $\mathbb{Q}$ and $G = [0, 1]$.

Comment: It is not because the closure of a closed set is a closed set. It is because the closure of a closed set is itself.

Answer (score 2):

Use the facts that for any subsets of metric or topological spaces, $X \subseteq Y \implies \overline{X} \subseteq \overline{Y}$ and $A = \overline{A}$ if $A$ is closed. You should prove these if you haven't.

You could also approach the problem more directly and take a limit point $x$ of $G$, show that it must be a limit point of $A$, and thus since $A$ is closed, $x \in A$ which then would imply  $\overline{G} \subseteq A$.

Comment: Isn't the closure of a set defined as the intersection of all closed sets containing the set?  And if that's the definition, the statement above is immediate.

Comment: Yea I guess it depends on the asker's defintion. The one I first learned is $\overline{A} = A \cup A'$ where $A'$ is the set of limit points of $A$.

Comment: That works in a metric space but the definition I'm using works in any topological space.